# angular 2 property not showing in model on page load

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

I am trying to learn how to create a reactive form using angular 2 and nested components. After reviewing a few tutorials and different solutions on git I have found [this by jonathanbruno](https://github.com/jonathanbruno/angular-nested-reactive-form), which seems to answer many of the question I had.

After pulling the solution I found that when run it the `description` value is only added to the model once the user starts typing in the input field and the default value I added does not show([I have added the solution to stackblitz to show what I mean](https://stackblitz.com/edit/basic-angular-nested-reactive-form-jonathanbruno?embed=1&file=app/parent/parent.component.html)).

I have looked for an answer to this problem and found [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/YSLDbWtJlZX5It1qGRq2?p=preview) which does not exibit the same issues. There are some obvious differences between the solution in "Plunker" and the solution by jonathanbruno, but I can't understand why the jonathanbruno solution isn't part of the model on page load.

My understanding is that `[(ngModel)]="parentModel.description"` enables the two way binding between the component and the HTML

**ParentComponent.ts**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html'
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  parentModel:ParentModel = new ParentModel();

  parentFormGroup:FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private _formBuilder:FormBuilder,
    private _cd:ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.parentFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      description: ['this does not show', Validators.required]
    });
    console.log(this.parentFormGroup);
  }

  addChild() {
    this.parentModel.children.push(new ChildModel());
    this._cd.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

**ParentComponent.html**

```html
<form [formGroup]="parentFormGroup">
    <label for="description">Description</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="parentModel.description" formControlName="description"><br>
    <button (click)="addChild()">Add Child</button><br>
    <app-child-list [childrenList] = "parentModel.children" [parentFormGroup]="parentFormGroup"></app-child-list>
    {{parentFormGroup.valid}}
    <pre>{{parentModel | json}}</pre>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working as it should :

If you check the output in the console of below code , you will get the idea ,

```
this.parentFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
    description: ['this does not show', Validators.required]
})
console.log(this.parentFormGroup.value);
```

that value is being set at first , then its overridden by the ngModel value that is not defined coz of that it goes blank

Comment: thanks, I think I was staring at that too long to realise that I was expecting `parentModel` to output the data held in `parentFormGroup`